# Vaadin throws an exception while refreshing the page

Tags: exception, reload, vaadin23

I am running tests for my Vaadin application and getting the following exception while clicking on the reload page button on the Chrome.

> 2022-12-08 19:50:52.543 ERROR 26592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.flow.router.InternalServerError      : There was an exception
> while trying to navigate to ''
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree
> to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its
> current state tree by calling removeFromTree  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.doSetTree(StateNode.java:739)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.lambda$setTree$3(StateNode.java:380)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.visitNodeTree(StateNode.java:688)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setTree(StateNode.java:380)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:274)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.NodeFeature.attachPotentialChild(NodeFeature.java:80)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.StateNodeNodeList.add(StateNodeNodeList.java:55)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementChildrenList.add(ElementChildrenList.java:44)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.impl.AbstractNodeStateProvider.insertChild(AbstractNodeStateProvider.java:104)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.insertChild(Node.java:386)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:163)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.dom.Node.appendChild(Node.java:147)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI$JavaScriptUIInternalUpdater.updateRoot(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:422)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.showRouteTarget(UIInternals.java:764)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:222)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:317)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.renderViewForRoute(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:280)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.connectClient(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:147)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:222)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:199)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:149)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.handleNode(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:132)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369)
> ~[flow-server-23.2.7.jar:23.2.7]  at
> com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106)
> ~[vaadin-spring-23.2.7.jar:na]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

I don't understand what does it mean and how to avoid it. If I restart application it does display what it suppose to do. It is not happening every time, but quite often.
What can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: This error typically means that you are trying to add component as I child to a other component, while it is already child in another component. The most typical reasons could be that you have scoped the component, sharing it with multiple sessions, using component via static, not returning new instance of a component in ComponentRenderer when using Grid or something like that. Also check the previous answers to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Can%27t+move+a+node+from+one+state+tree+to+another

Comment: I did check previous answers and do not see anything that resembles my case.
I do not use static components and practically all my Spring beans have been annotated as prototypes. I am just clicking on reload button on the browser. My application is a single page, therefore I am not sharing it with multiple sessions.

Comment: How can I find, what component is causing this exception? What I can do to avoid it? It is impossible to restart the application every time when someone click on reload button.

Comment: I did open a bug report with Vaadin/flow last week. Unfortunately, Vaadin team are not rushing to help. I even upgraded to the latest version (23.3.0) but exception still occur for every browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an SPA, adding @UIScope everywhere solved the issue, because trying to switch temporally to V24.2 to see the enhanced message exception that indicate exactly the component causing the problem [github](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/18019) is too complex, there are too many big changes between V23 and 24